# Transpose a matrix using for loops (only)

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, matrix

I'm trying to create a code for transpose an array

I come from Matlab, and I create this code (wich works well):

```
A = [1,2,3,0,-2,0 ; 0,2,0,1,2,3];

n = size(A);

for i=1:n(2)

    for j=1:n(1)

     M(i,j) = A(j,i) 

    end
end
```

In Python I'm tryng this (using the same logic):

```
M = [
    [1,2,3,0,-2,0],
    [0,2,0,1,2,3]
    ]

LM = (len(M),len(M[0]))
print(LM)

Maux=[[]]
print(Maux)


for i in range(0,LM[1]):
    for j in range(0,LM[0]):

        Maux[i][j] = M[j][i]
        print(Maux)
```

But when I compile, the error is:

Maux[i][j] = M[j][i] IndexError: list assignment index out of range

And I know using numpy I can create this code as well:

```
import numpy as np 

A = [

    [1,2,3,0,-2,0],
    [0,2,0,1,2,3]

    ]

T = np.transpose(A)

print(A)
print(T)
```

But I need create this code only using for loops, any idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```py
Maux=[[]]
```

is a list containing a single empty list. This has a shape of (1, 0) which is why you get a index out of bounds error. You need to initialize `Maux` to be the same shape as `M`. So something like

```py
Maux = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `Maux` to handle to transpose:

```
Maux=[[0 for i in range(len(M))] for j in range(len(M[0]))]
```

Your code, as is, is asking python to assign values to locations which do not exist (because `Maux` is empty lists).

In summary, you need to create `Maux` as an empty list of lists with the same dimensions as the transpose: if `M` is `n` by `m`, then `Maux` must be `m` by `n` not 1 by 0.